# Getting the url query parameters in Play Template

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to access the url query string parameters from within my Play Template

so I have the following url:

```
myexample.com/product?q=mytermhere
```

and I want to get access to this 'q' parameter in my template code for use in javascript. Is this possible without going via the whole controller route. Thanks

Comment: Pass this querystring as a parameter to your template file

Answer (score 3):

> for use in javascript

Never, ever put user input - such as a query parameter - into a script tag.  Ever.  It doesn't matter what escaping you do, if you do this, you will have an XSS vulnerability in your code.  Guaranteed.  There is no way to do it safely.

If you want to access user input from JavaScript, put it somewhere in your HTML - eg in a meta tag, or in a data attribute on a regular tag.

To do that is easy, on the request is a property called `queryString`, it's a map contain the query string parameters.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but on this occasion all I am doing is using it  in a simple function to highlight a search term in the text of the page. There is no possibility of xss causing any havoc. It is not going anywhere near a database and is not persisted. The q="searchterm" is just passed into a function on the client to highlight the text. That is all.

Comment: That's exactly what I was worried about, what you're describing there is a classic reflected XSS vulnerability - data doesn't need to be persisted to be vulnerable to XSS, reflected XSS vulnerabilities can be exploited by simply redirecting a user to a page that echos (or passes to a function, as you put it) data that came in the query string in a context (ie inside a script tag) that is unsafe.

Comment: So where is the harm? What exactly can they do - they can't harm the database, they can't get into the application code, they can't do anything to change the state of the system. They can entertain themselves all they want by redirecting to an other page, but a new user will still be served the correct page.

Comment: If I redirect you to, or somehow coerce you to click a link to http://myexample.com/product?q=<img%20src=x%20onerror=alert(0)%20/> and the q parameter is vulnerable to a reflected XSS attack, then that alert(0) code will execute on the page.  Substitute alert(0) for something that makes malicious AJAX calls etc.